# Appending OnFocus function to textbox using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery

I have two textboxes and two radio buttons.Clicking on each radio button, i am disabling corresponding textbox and enabling other one.I want to change the blinking cursor from the disabled textbox, so that iam usng this javascript function `onfocus="this.blur()"`.How i can append this event to the readonly text box and removing from other one...

Comment: you can bind/unbind events using unbind()/bind() jquery functions. See some examples: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

(

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
               if(value="text1")
                 {

                    $("#text1").focus();
                    $("#text2").blur();

                 }
                 else if(value="text2")
                {
                   $("#text1").blur();
                   $("#text2").focus();

                 }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".radiobtn").click(function (event) {
var rtbxid = $(this).val();
if (rtbxid === '1') {
    $("#tbx1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#tbx2").removeAttr("disabled").focus();       
}else{
    $("#tbx1").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
    $("#tbx2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAk5e/3/)

Comment: If we use remove function, it wont get in the Post array

Comment: @Warrior Post array? can you provide your DOM and make your question more specific?